# Авторизация через прокси AIP вк python

Tags: python, вконтакте

На Украине заблокирован VK, поэтому я использую прокси.

```
import requests
import json
proxies = {"https": "188.40.141.216:3128"}
token='948a6df442fec617f43603e21be74feb033f67c47b1fb8ad239e6812bf4d740256a2bd492cddec2c3880a'
r=requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get', params={'owner_id':-27797026,'count':1,'offset':0,'access_token':token,'v':5.52},proxies=proxies)#получаем последний пост
print(r.json())
```

Ошибка:

> `{'error': {'error_code': 5, 'error_msg': 'User authorization failed:         access_token was given to another ip address.', 'request_params': [{'key': 'oauth', 'value': '1'}, {'key': 'method', 'value': 'wall.get'}, {'key':  'owner_id', 'value': '-27797026'}, {'key': 'count', 'value': '1'}, {'key':  'offset', 'value': '0'}, {'key': 'v', 'value': '5.52'}]}}`

Хотя когда я вставляю в браузер `FreeU` [ссылку](https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=-27797026&count=1&offset0&v=5.52&access_token=948a6df442fec617f43603e21be74feb033f67c47b1fb8ad239e6812bf4d740256a2bd492cddec2c3880a) то все работает

Comment: попробуйте в yandex translate или схожий сервис вставить фразу: *"access_token was given to another ip address"*

Comment: Спасибо за совет, сам не понимаю как недодумался.Нужно было Права доступа для токена пользователя указать offline

Comment: если думаете, что нашли решение, можете его как свой ответ опубликовать—[это явно приветствуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: А прокси на валидность проверял ? У вк свои базы есть (черные списки), авторизация проходит через бразуер ?

Answer (score 1):

Ты пытаешься использовать токен, который привязан к твоему ip. Получи токен используя прокси, а затем делай запросы используя его и прокси, через который ты его получил.